# Xamarin forms: Absolute Layout Listview Scrolling is not working

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, absolutelayout

I have a listview inside an AbsoluteLayout and my problem is listview scrolling is not working.

**Please see the below screenshot of code:**

[image]

**And the output screen is like below:**

[image]

I have added `AbsoluteLayout` for putting the `Imagebutton` on top of Listview. If I cover the `AbsoluteLayout` with a `scrollview`, then scrolling works, but the `Imagebutton` is not showing on top of Listview. It is placed on the bottom after listview items.

Please suggest a solution for this, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could warp the **ListView** only with the **ScrollView** and put the **ScrollView** in the **AbsoluteLayout** .

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <ScrollView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
        <ListView >
            //...
        </ListView>
    </ScrollView>
   //...other control 
</AbsoluteLayout>
```